# Unable to Boot Into Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot

When I boot Ubuntu, it asks me if I want generic version, or recovery mode. I choose generic mode and it goes straight to a purple screen and doesn't do anything else. I love using ubuntu, but now I can't :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already done so, you could try booting with the `nomodeset` kernel boot option and see if that helps.

#### Adding the `nomodeset` kernel option for a single boot

You can edit the boot instructions for the GRUB menu entry to add the `nomodeset` option to see if it corrects your graphics problem.

1. Boot to the GRUB boot menu. An example of the menu is shown in the screenshot below.

   [image: screenshot showing an example of the GRUB boot menu]

   **Note:** If you do **not** see the GRUB boot menu when you boot, try pressing and holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> key immediately after the BIOS portion of the boot completes.
2. Select (highlight) the GRUB boot menu entry for the Ubuntu kernel you wish to boot.
3. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the GRUB boot commands for the selected boot menu entry.
4. Look near the bottom of the list of commands for lines similar to

   `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=bc6f8146-1523-46a6-8b\`

   `6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash`

   `initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic`
5. Change the middle line in (4) by adding the kernel boot parameter `nomodeset` to the end of the line (i.e. after `ro  quiet splash`).

   For this example you would change

   `6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash` 

   to 

   `6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash nomodeset`
6. ***Without*** leaving this GRUB edit screen, press either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot using the modified kernel options.

**Note:** These changes are **not** persistent. Any change to the kernel boot options made this way will only affect the next boot and only if you start that boot by pressing either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> while still in GRUB edit mode.